# MS Graph API to get Teams analytics

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am looking if there is any API Graph that is made available to get the analytics of teams in MS teams.
I have checked the site,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

But there is no API to get Analytics data as in below image.

[image]

..

Comment: Currently, only APIs are available for overall [Microsoft Teams user activity reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/microsoft-teams-user-activity-reports?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Comment: Hi KumarV, I'm looking for the same thing. Found something interesting in the past year and a half regarding that?